# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returning the same cells for different indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier works for the first 7 cells and then it randomly starts to reuse the cells from 1-7 for 8-14 and so on... However it should be creating new cells as they dont exist yet.
This is my code-

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    NSLog(indexPath.description)
    var cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("matchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)) as! MatchCell
    if (cell.created == nil) {
        cell = configureCell(cell, withIndex: indexPath.section)
    }
    return cell
}
```

No Idea why this is happening. It works fine for the first 7 cells...

Comment: `if cell.created == nil` it is probably the culprit

Comment: indexPath.section ??

Comment: each cell has a space between it so im using heightForFooterInSection and using numberOfRowsInSection to set 1 row per section. Each section acts as a row this way...

Comment: cell.created is an optional value that is set to true once created. This works fine the first 7 times the code runs. I can't imagine how this would be the culprit.

Comment: As other have pointed out, it's likely because the cells are being reused. The answer depends upon what you're doing in `configureCell`. If you're adding controls and the like, that is probably better done in the `init` method (or `awakeFromNib` method) of the custom cell, rather than having the view controller do that. Describe how the cell was associated with that identifier (cell prototype? registered a NIB or class with that identifier?) and what you're doing in `configureCell` and we could advise further.

Answer (score 2):

Cells are reusable so once they go off-screen they will be returned to you from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` so your `if (cell.created == nil)` will not be true for reused cells.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Don't check for `cell.created == nil`
2. Override `prepareForReuse` in your `MatchCell` and do any cleanup for reuse (and set `created` to be nil)

I personally like the second option.
[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse) has more info on `prepareForReuse`.

Comment: But as I stated before it works fine for the first 7 cells. Furthermore, cell.created == nil is true 100% of the time until that cell's subviews are setup at which i manually call self.created = true. I have verified that it works with NSLog... The problem is not that if statement. The problem is that dequeueResuableCellWithIdentifier is returning an already created cell for the wrong indexpath. It returns the cell at indexpath.section = 1 when the current indexpath.section is 8

Comment: As the docs for `prepareForReuse` says: "For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. The table view's `delegate` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should always reset all content when reusing a cell."

Comment: @user3781268 as juhan_h said try to override prepareForReuse method and clear your cell in this method. Recently I have same problem, it is was useful for me :)

Comment: @user3781268 you are misunderstanding how `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` works - the emphasis is on the *reusable* not on the *forIndexPath* - the index path provides a hint but it does not mean that you will get a new cell for each index path or even that you will get the same cell each time this method is invoked for a given index path.  All cells with the same reuse identifier are considered interchangeable and you need to configure each cell appropriately as it may be new or reused at any time

Comment: @user3781268 As the previous commenters have explained: Cells will be reused. UIKit will not guarantee that it will give you a vanilla cell when enough cells have already been created because creating cells is expensive. The "reusable" in the method name is a pretty good giveaway. On a side note I baffled me the first time as well :)